# Java error "Cannot find symbol - method(validIndex)"

Tags: java, bluej

I am working through an assignment for my course. I was asked to create a valid index method that checked whether the int entered was a valid index for my ArrayList. This method compiled fine and worked fine.

A further exercise asked me to then use this validIndex method within other methods. I have tried to do that within my removeFile method. The removeFile method is meant to call the validIndex method in order to check whether the index parameter of removeFile is a valid index for the ArrayList. However my file now refuses to compile giving me the error

> cannot find symbol - method validIndex()

The code is below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A class to hold details of audio files.
 * 
 * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */
public class MusicOrganizer
{
    // An ArrayList for storing the file names of music files.
    private ArrayList<String> files;     
    /**
     * Create a MusicOrganizer
     */
    public MusicOrganizer()
    {
        files = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * Add a file to the collection.
     * @param filename The file to be added.
     */
    public void addFile(String filename)
    {
        files.add(filename);
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of files in the collection.
     * @return The number of files in the collection.
     */
    public int getNumberOfFiles()
    {
        return files.size();
    }

    /**
     * List a file from the collection.
     * @param index The index of the file to be listed.
     */
    public void listFile(int index)
    {
        if(index >= 0 && index < files.size()) {
            String filename = files.get(index);
            System.out.println(filename);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove a file from the collection.
     * @param index The index of the file to be removed.
     */
    public void removeFile(int index)
    {
        if(files.validIndex() = true){
            files.remove(index);
        }
    }

    // Problem with this method. If ArrayList is empty then the indexes variable returns minus 1
    public void checkIndex(int index)
    {
        int size = files.size();
        int indexes = size - 1;
        if (index >= 0 && index <= indexes){
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid index number.");
            System.out.println("The index should be between 0 and " + indexes);
        }
    }

    public boolean validIndex(int index)
    {

        if (index >= 0 && index <= files.size()-1){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }



}
```

If someone could point out why my code won't compile that would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you meant to use `validIndex(index)` instead of `files.validIndex() = true`. `files` is a `List` which does not contain this method.

Comment: You implemented the method `validIndex()' with a parameter from type int. You try to call this method without any parameter. That's a big difference, in order you can override methods.

Comment: It's out of scope, but validIndex can has one line - just `index >= 0 && index <= files.size()-1`. You're learning, so maybe it will help to improve your code readability :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to call your own method validIndex, you are calling it wrong.

To call your validIndex method, you should do the following:

```
public void removeFile(int index)
    {
        if(this.validIndex(index)){
            files.remove(index);
        }
    }
```

Note that `files` is an object of the `ArrayList` class. So the statement

```
files.validIndex()
```

points to method called `validIndex()` in the `ArrayList` class, which doesn't exist. The method exists in your class so the only way of accessing it is with the current object. Change the if statement to

```
if(this.validIndex(...) == true){ ... }
```

or simply

```
if(validIndex(...) == true){ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! Can I ask you for a small explanation of why it works though? Do method calls to methods within the same class always require the this prefix in java?

Comment: @ed2101 No, you don't need to add `this`. It is very helpful if you i.e. have field named `test` and method parameter is also called `test` and you want to access field, not parameter. Here `this` may be omitted

Answer (score 0):

this line.

```
if(files.validIndex() = true){
```

1) What index is a valid index? You need to use a parameter, as defined by the `validIndex` method

2) `files` does not have a `validIndex` method, since it is a `List` object. Your method is defined in your current class, so do not prefix the method call with `files`. You can optionally replace it with `this`

3) You are using assignment operation, not boolean condition. Either remove it because checking for true is redundant, or use two equals

So.

```
if (validIndex(index)) {
```